# inject javascript in WKWebView to get the src attribut of a clicked image

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I want to inject a javascript code in a webkitview that gets the src attribute of a clicked image when the user clicks on it.
I found also that some images don't put their src attribute directly in the img balise but it is injected by a class in the balise. I found this script that gets the clicked Html element in the webview :

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        var tagClicked = document.elementFromPoint(evt.pageX - window.pageXOffset, evt.pageY - window.pageYOffset);
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(tagClicked.outerHTML.toString());
        });
```

exemple of src attribut injected by a class: `<img alt="Chaussure de football enfant terrains secs Agility 900 FG JR grise et bleue" class="source-medium">`

it this case I can fetch the src attribute from the returned string if it is an image but if the src attribute is injected by a class in the img balise I can't get it from the returned string. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: *"exemple of src attribut injected by a class"* There's no `src` attribute there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be glad to know it's much easier than that, because the event object has a property called `target` which is the element that was clicked. Since you're interested in `img` elements, we don't have to worry about it being a child element of the one you want, so we can just use `evt.target` directly.

To make it even easier, `HTMLImageElement` objects have a `src` property which provides the full, resolved URL of the image, so:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(evt.target.src);
    }
});
```

But if you really want the `outerHTML` instead:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(evt.target.outerHTML);
    }
});
```

Assuming this is an HTML page, you can rely on the `tagName` being in all caps (even if it isn't in the HTML the page was parsed from).

Comment: Hey T.J! thank you for your reply, you just gave me a great answer I didn't think it will be so easy to do it. But unfortunately it doesn't work in all cases, for example, I can't retrieve the src of these two images:  https://www.decathlon.fr/p/chaussure-de-football-enfant-terrain-sec-agility-900-fg-bleu-rouge/_/R-p-192471?mc=8497506&c=BLEU  and  https://store.canon.fr/canon-boitier-canon-eos-rp-objectif-rf-24-105mm-f-4l-is-usm-bague-d-adaptation-monture-ef-eos-r/3380C044/ as I sad in my question there are images that don't pass src attribute directly like the first example